# comparing variabel between 2 file C#

Tags: c#, class, xamarin.forms, static

Im pretty new to C coding and most of all C# so the problem i have is to understand how it works. So what i want really is that when you press on a grid you will get a unique id depending what item is displayed in the grid, and on pressing on the grid you will go to a new page where i want to display the item.id

File 1

```
foreach (var item in list)
 {
        TapGestureRecognizer gridTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        gridTap.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
        {

            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MarketItemPage());

            item.Id = GridIdentifier.Grid_id; // item.id is the id of the choosen item = static int in class

        };

}
```

File 2

```
 public void Update()
    {
        string gridid = GridIdentifier.Grid_id.ToString();

        grid.Children.Add(new Label
        {

            Text = gridid,
            FontSize = 16,
            FontFamily = "Arial",
            TextColor = Color.Red,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,

        });

    }
```

Class

```
public static class GridIdentifier
{
    public static int Grid_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the simplest way to pass values between classes is as a parameter to the constructor of MarketItemPage()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. One way would be to pass the item's `Id` to the constructor of the `MarketItemPage`.

For more options, look at the Xamarin information for [Passing data when navigating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal#passing-data-when-navigating)